# Setting a cookie from another domain B meant to be used as a first party cookie for website A when visiting later the website A

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, third-party-cookies

Please help me clarify my understanding of cookies, and what can be done in this scenario

1. My company `mycompany-example.com` has a widget service that injects html & JS code and useful content on a given website @ `api.mycompany-example.com`
2. A customer C has a website `website.mycustomer-example.com` where he adds our widget. They add a div and a script that requests html/JS code from our API @ `api.mycompany-example.com` and fills this div with content (the response is a JS response)
3. This widget deployed on the customer C, then performs additional API requests to update its own content based on user actions
4. The content created from this widget includes links that when clicked will open new tabs to pages of our website `www.mycompany-example.com`
5. When reaching `www.mycompany-example.com`, we want to accurately track from which widget our customer comes from, if possible without resorting to URL params or whatever ad tracking cookie that could be blocked (currently we are using URL params in the URLs of 4.).

Question : can I create, from 2. and 3. a server side httpOnly cookie (containing a `widget_id`) of domain `mycompany-example.com`, that can be used during step 5. when the user visits our website so we know which widget they come from ?

Correct my understanding, but when creating such a cookie at step 2. or 3., it would be considered a third party cookie for the customer website `website.mycustomer-example.com`. This is what is going to be dropped in the future of chrome (and the web in general?) and we should stop using.

However, will the browser still allow setting this cookie, that could later be used if/when the user ends up visiting our website ?

Are there gaps in my understanding or security problems I'm missing ?

Answer (score 2):

When the HTML page on `*.mycustomer-example.com` contains a `<script>` element that loads Javascript from a different domain like `*.mycompany-example.com` (your step 2), the Javascript response can set a cookie. But this would be a third-party cookie and hence be blocked by browsers (Google Chrome will enforce such blocking [starting in 2024](https://privacysandbox.com/open-web/#the-privacy-sandbox-timeline)).

Even making it a [partitioned cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Privacy/Partitioned_cookies) would not help you: The HTTP header

```
Set-Cookie: widget_id=xxx; SameSite=None; Secure; Partitioned
```

in the Javascript response will *set* the cookie in the browser, but the browser will only *resend* it while the top-level page is still from `*.mycustomer-example.com`. It will *not send* the cookie when the user opens a new tab at `*.mycompany-example.com` (your step 5).

Your use case of using the same cookie within and without a cross-site embedding is indistinguishable from ad tracking and will therefore be blocked. I suggest that you simply place the information that you want transported either in a URL parameter or in a form field. In the latter case, the links in your step 4 become form submission buttons:

```html
<form action="/content/1" type="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" target="_blank">
  <input name="widget_id" value="1" hidden>
  <input type="submit" value="Open new tab">
</form>
```

and clicking such a button produces a request like

```
POST /content/1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

widget_id=1
```

which contains the `widget_id` in its body without "polluting" the URL.

Comment: One of the disadvantage I see, is the need to avoid duplicating content/analytics because of an extra parameter (eg `/content/1?widget_id=1` vs `/content/1?widget_id=2`) that could be interpreted as being a different page. This can usually be configured in tools as "ignored URL params", but it it still extra configuration that needs to be done and may involve several teams, so if this can be avoided it is still best imo. But your answer seems to suggest we don't have a choice anyways...

Comment: See my augmented answer.