# Accessibility of partition cookies

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, iframe, browser, third-party-cookies

While engaged in a project, I recently encountered a specific situation involving cookies.

To illustrate, consider a scenario where I have a domain named `parent.com` containing an iframe named `iframe.com`.
Consequently, all cookies generated by iframe.com are treated as third-party cookies. In light of Google's upcoming phase-out of third-party cookies, I have currently configured these cookies as partition cookies. Specifically, The partition key is set for all these cookies as `parent.com` by the browser, making them accessible within that domain.

However, I've encountered an issue when visiting a domain like `a.iframe.com` as the main domain in a new tab. In this case, partition cookies are not accessible, unlike unpartitioned cookies, which were functioning correctly.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this matter.

Comment: You write "I've set the partition key", but the partition key is only set by the browser. What do you mean? And if you set a cookie with partition key `https://parent.com` and later want to access it from a top-level domain ending with `.iframe.com`, then your use case is indistinguishable from cross-site tracking. Partitioned cookies prevent cross-site tracking, that's why they are not accessible in this way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting a cookie from another domain B meant to be used as a first party cookie for website A when visiting later the website A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77573185/setting-a-cookie-from-another-domain-b-meant-to-be-used-as-a-first-party-cookie)

Comment: Yes, correct the partition key is set by the browser. I'm only sending the cookie as a partition cookie. I have updated the same. Let me have a look at the solution you have provided.